# Database Integrity on 3 Tables

Tags: sql-server, join, primary-key

I have 3 tables

- `Project` : `ProjectID` (primary key)
- `Bugs`: `ProjectID, BugID` (primary key)
- `BugLogs`: `BugID, BugLogID` (primary key)

There are:

- Multiple bugs on a project
- Multiple bug logs on the bugs

How would I insert a project that has a bug (s) and then bug Logs on bugs efficiently into these tables?

Thanks

Comment: How do you define 'efficiently' here?

Comment: Generally the inserts would be done at seperate times.  So writing a single procedure makes no sense. I'd likely write 1 package or 3 procedures to handle the inserts/updates/deletes of elements in these tables; passing in parameters defining the actions/data.

Answer (score 3):

Well here you need to write individual insert statements. Joins will only be used when querying the data..

You can do the following if bugid is an identity column:

```
DECLARE @bugid bigint
INSERT INTO Bugs (Projectid,other COLUMNS...)
VALUES (values1,VALUES....)

SELECT @bugid= SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO BugLogs(Bugid,other COLUMNS...)
VALUES(@bugid,....)
```

Alternatively you can use Output clause to get the bugid. This will work in all scenarios:

```
DECLARE @bugid bigint
INSERT INTO Bugs (Projectid,other COLUMNS...)
OUTPUT INSERTED.BugId INTO @bugid
VALUES (values1,VALUES....)

INSERT INTO BugLogs(Bugid,other COLUMNS...)
VALUES(@bugid,....)
```

Comment: You can follow the same pattern for Project Id.

Answer (score 2):

Joins have nothing to do with Inserts. Joins only come into play when you want to query the data.

If you have your declarative referential integrity in place, then you are going to have to insert records in the following order: **Project**, **Bugs**, **BugLogs**.

If you are working in Microsoft SQL Server, and are using identity columns, after you insert a row, you can use the scope_identity() function to retrieve the primary key assigned and use that to set you foreign keys.